# Как конвертировать LPWSTR в LPCSTR

Tags: c, winapi

У меня возникли проблемы с работой программы.

```
int __cdecl main(){
LPWSTR * argv;
int n;

argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &n);
DeleteFile(argv[1]);
                  }
```

CommandLineToArgv возвращает LPWSTR, а DeleteFile очевидно нужен LPCSTR.

Как один тип данных конвертировать в другой ?

Comment: DeleteFile**W**

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, вроде бы я читал о DeleteFileW, но принимаемый тип данных там такой же как и в DeleteFileA.

Comment: Ссылки на документацию: [DeleteFileA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea), [DeleteFileW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew). Если вы используете CommandLineToArgv**W**, GetCommandLine**W**, то будьте последовательны и используйте DeleteFile**W**.

Comment: Или вместо этого зоопарка с конвертацией, использовать `CommandLineToArgvA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для конвертации строк UNICODE<=>ANSI в WinAPI есть функции [WideCharToMultiByte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) и обратная ей [MultiByteToWideChar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar). Но именно в вашем случае лучше использовать вместо функции `DeleteFile` ее UNICODE версию `DeleteFileW`. Во-первых это проще, чем конвертировать строку, а во-вторых, она будет нормально работать с кириллическими именами файлов ( в отличие от `DeleteFile`, с которой могут быть проблемы).

Comment: Да, уже знаю, спасибо, теперь осталось разобраться с CreateProcess, могу я в случае чего тут задать некоторые вопросы о ней ?

Comment: @rootkit.sys, можете конечно, но лучше не тут, а отдельным вопросом. Правила ресурса здесь такие.